# Find $a$ and $b$ such that

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image: Image of matrix]

This is the matrix. I cannot find any examples in our notes or the textbook that shows how to solve this. I tried by setting an equation equal to $a$ then using the equation I got for $a$ to find $b$. And once I found $b$, I got $-\frac {15}{7}$ but it is incorrect. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: It says the correct answer for b is -3. I'm not sure where this comes from. But this means a is also -3.

Comment: perhaps you should include that as an edit into your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear equations for each component are
$$a+7b=-24$$
$$4a+8b=-36$$
And the third equation is same as the first equation, so we need not consider it separately. Now, divide both sides of the second equation by $4$, we get,
$$a+2b=-9$$
Subtract this equation from the first one, we get,
$$5b=-24+9=-15$$
$$\Longrightarrow b= -3$$
Substitute this value of $b$ in any of the equations to get $a = -3$.

Hope it is helpful:)

Comment: Yes this makes sense, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome:)

Answer (score 1):

You have a system of $3$ equations in $2$  unknowns.

One way is to row-reduce the augmented matrix:     $\left (\begin{array}{rr|r}1&7&-24 \\4&8&-36\\1&7&-24\end{array}\right)\to\left (\begin{array}{rr|r}1&7&-24\\0&-20&60\\0&0&0\end{array}\right )\to\left (\begin{array}{rr|r}1&7&-24\\0&1&-3\\0&0&0\end{array}\right)$.

Now we can *back-substitute*:

$b=-3$ and $1a+7(-3)=-24\implies a=-3$.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

- Just focus on the first two rows, there, you have two linearly independent equations and two unknowns.
- After you solve the first two rows, verify that it satisfies the third row.